# How to draw an fullscreen overlay and text+text field over it?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Is there a way to draw fullscreen overlay, and then draw a label + textfield over it?

What I already did:

When user clicks button, screen should be covered by overlay.

in the **AppDelegate.m** button action method I wrote:

```
NSRect frame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
self.mainWindow  = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
[self.mainWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
[self.mainWindow setOpaque:NO];
[self.mainWindow setLevel:CGShieldingWindowLevel()];
[self.mainWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7]];
[self.mainWindow orderFrontRegardless];
NSApplicationPresentationOptions options = NSApplicationPresentationDisableProcessSwitching + NSApplicationPresentationHideDock + NSApplicationPresentationDisableForceQuit + NSApplicationPresentationDisableSessionTermination + NSApplicationPresentationDisableHideApplication;
[NSApp setPresentationOptions:options];
```

It's working nice, but without any animations & I really don't know how to draw objects (labels/textfields) over it?

Either, should I move this method into another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as for animation, there are many ways.. Id do

```
mainWindow.alphaValue = 0;
[mainWindow orderFrontRegardless];
[[mainWindow animator] setAlphaValue:1.0];
```

as for the label, just add a NSTextField with a HUGE NSFont, as a subview

```
NSTextField *label = ... 
[[mainWindow contentView] addSubview:label];
```

p.s. just like with the label, you can add any other views :)